# How do I interpret an independent variable which is a log(%)?

Tags: regression, interpretation, logarithm

My linear regression is:

School's average test score ~ log(%FSM)

%FSM = the percentage of pupils at the school who are eligible for free school meals (an indicator of low socio-economic status).

The coefficient for log(%FSM) is -10.

Do I interpret this as: a 1% increase in the %FSM pupils is associated with a decrease of 0.1 in average test score?

Or, because this is a log of a % is the interpretation different from the above? I think this is also a 1% increase, NOT a 1 percentage point increase. Is there a clearer way to make this distinction in my interpretation?

Comment: This is a FAQ: please search our site for [log regression dependent interpretation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interpret*+log+regression+dependent+-logistic+answers%3A1).

Comment: Hello, thank you for sharing the link, but I cannot find a post which specifically talks about the effect of a log % IV on a non-log DV.

Comment: We have a great many posts concerning all possible combinations of logs (and other transformations) on the DVs and the IVs.  [Here's a search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+independent+variable+log+answers%3A1+-logistic).